# Handling updates to store with React/Redux and lifecycle events

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rails-api

I'm using React with Redux on my front end and using the Rails API to handle my backend. At present, I am trying to update a list of articles based on user addition of an article. The ArticleForm component fires an action creator that is successfully updating my ArticleList. However, at present the life cycle method componentWillUpdate is firing continuously making axios requests to Rails, and Rails keeps querying my database and sending back the articleList.

Note: I have tried using shouldComponentUpdate as such to no avail, the DOM doesn't update:

```
// shouldComponentUpdate(newProps){
  //   return newProps.articleList !== this.props.articleList
  // }
```

My question is: how can I use React's lifecycle methods to avoid this from happening and *only* happening when my articleList updates. Am I going down the wrong path using lifecycle methods? I'm fairly new to React/Redux so any and all advice is helpful!

I have the following container:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import ArticleForm from './ArticleForm'
import ArticleList from './ArticleList'
import removeArticle from '../actions/removeArticle'
import fetchArticles from '../actions/fetchArticles'
import updateArticleList from '../actions/updateArticleList'

class DumbArticleContainer extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchArticles()
  }

  // shouldComponentUpdate(newProps){
  //   return newProps.articleList !== this.props.articleList
  // }

  componentWillUpdate(newProps){
    if (newProps.articleList.articleList.count !== this.props.articleList.articleList.count){
      this.props.updateArticleList()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ArticleForm />
        <ArticleList articleList={this.props.articleList} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ArticleContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DumbArticleContainer)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {articleList: state.articleList}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({removeArticle, fetchArticles, updateArticleList}, dispatch);
}

export default ArticleContainer
```

here is the ArticleForm

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import addArticle from '../actions/addArticle.js'

class ArticleForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {disabled: true}
  }

  /* Most article elements are displayed conditionally based on local state */
  toggleState(){
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled
    })
  }

  handleFormSubmit(props) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const {resetForm} = this.props

    this.props.addArticle(props).then( ()=>{
      var router = require('react-router')
      router.browserHistory.push('/dashboard')
      resetForm()
    })
  }

  render() {
    const disabled = this.state.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''
    const hidden = this.state.disabled ? 'hidden' : ''

    const {fields: {title, url}, handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="article-form">

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
              <button className="article-form-btn"
                      hidden={!hidden}
                      onClick={this.toggleState.bind(this)}
                      >
                      + Add Article
              </ button>
              <input className="article-form-input"
                     hidden={hidden}
                     type="textarea"
                     placeholder="Title"
                     {...title}
                     />

              <input className="article-form-input"
                     hidden={hidden}
                     type="textarea"
                     placeholder="Paste Link"
                     {...url}
                     />

              { this.state.disabled
                ? ''
                : <input className="article-form-input"
                         type="submit"
                         value="Save"
                        />
              }
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'articleForm',
    fields: ['title', 'url']
  },
  null,
  { addArticle })(ArticleForm);
```

and the ArticleList

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import removeArticle from '../actions/removeArticle.js'
import fetchArticles from '../actions/fetchArticles'
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap'

class Article extends Component {


  render(){
    var articleList = this.props.articleList.articleList

    return(
      <div>
        <ListGroup>

          { articleList.slice(articleList.length - 10, articleList.length)
            .map( (article) => {
              return(
                <ListGroupItem href="#" header={article.attributes.title}>
                  {article.attributes.url}
                </ListGroupItem>
              )}
          )}

        </ListGroup>
        <div> View All Articles </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

const ArticleList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Article)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {articleList: state.articleList}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return  {removeArticle: bindActionCreators({removeArticle}, dispatch),
  fetchArticles: bindActionCreators({fetchArticles}, dispatch)
    }
}

export default ArticleList
```

action creator:

So here is my action creator import axios from 'axios'

```
import axios from 'axios'

function updateArticleList(){

  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles'
  return axios.get(url).then( (response)=> {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_ARTICLE_LIST',
      payload: response.data
    }
  })
}
export default updateArticleList
```

and reducer:

```
   export default function articleReducer(state = {articleList: []}, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'FETCH_ARTICLES':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {articleList: action.payload.data});
    case 'UPDATE_ARTICLE_LIST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {articleList: action.payload.data});
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

There is no issue with the store nor the action creators nor the reducers, they are all working pretty well. I can't really replicate the hundreds of queries rails is performing but am happy to include other code should anyone need to see it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should include your actions and reducers. They're very important. Also, only fire the very first fetch from the mount lifetime method. Fire the others from action creators based on user actions, such as form submit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip---I updated with 2 new code blocks. so you're saying create a new action creator like updateArticles?

Comment: FETCH_ARTICLES and UPDATE_ARTICLE_LIST actions do the same thing and toy only need one. URL should probably be relative. Action creators are not actions. Async action creators usually fire multiple actions. These actions could be any actions. Often the action returned or fired by an action creator bares the same or similar type name(s) as the action creator's name but this is not a requirement. Basing your fetch on the count of articles is a bad idea. Putting it in your addArticle function may be better. Don't a fetch might not even be needed if your client has all the info.

Comment: If your server generates an ID or otherwise changes the article then this may not be possible of course but if toy can avoid a fetch then that's always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mapDispatchToProps` is using `bindActionCreators` wrong.  Instead of

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return  {removeArticle: bindActionCreators({removeArticle}, dispatch),
  fetchArticles: bindActionCreators({fetchArticles}, dispatch)
    }
}
```

you should use

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({removeArticle, fetchArticles}, dispatch);
}
```

`bindActionCreators` can, as the name suggests, bind more than one action creator.

This probably won't solve your issue but an answer is the only place I could put this nicely.

Note that you'll need to fix how you're using it as well. No more double names.

Comment: I figured I was doing something wrong there. Thanks, I changed it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to keep a state called **shouldUpdateList**. Whenever I fire a action that changes the list(add or update an item to the list), I set **shouldUpdateList** to **true**. Then,set it back to **false** whenever I fire ajax action to fetch the list.

The lifecycle event I use to check **shouldUpdateList** is **componentWillReceiveProps**, if it's **true** I fire a fetch action.

EDIT: I mean keep **shouldUpdateList** state in Redux store. Something like:

```
const INIT_STATE = {
    list: [],
    shouldUpdateList: false
}
```

then

```
case Action.ADD_NEW:
    //set shouldUpdateList to true
case Action.FETCH_LIST:
    //set shouldUpdateList to false
```

lastly, in component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.shouldUpdateList === true) {
        //dispatch action FETCH_LIST
    }
}
```

Comment: So give the component it's own 'local' state? I had thought that that was one of the things to be avoided with Redux?

Comment: @tqr_aupa_atleti i edited my answer to clear myself. Please check it. :D